# How to update start Time(!) in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to change the start time of an Event, wich I draged into the calendar.

The Event comes from an external Source like this:

```
//initialize the external events

    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

        /* // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });
        */
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            id: $(this).data('id')
        };          

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });
```

I want to change/update the start Time and Title - if necessary - of the Event in a modal Dialog. It seems to work fine, but everytime I add another Event by dragging and want to change it, it changes all other dragged Events, too.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


           //Sending data to modal:         

            $('#modal').modal('show');
            $("#input_title").val(calEvent.title);
            var my_time = moment(calEvent.start).format('LT');
            $("#input_time").val(my_time);
            var my_date = moment(calEvent.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            $("#input_date").val(my_date);

            // waiting for button 'save' click:
            $('.btn-primary').on('click', function (myEvent) {

                    calEvent.title = $("#input_title").val();
                    var my_input_time = $("#input_time").val();
                    var momentTimeObj = moment(my_input_time, 'HH:mm:ss');
                    var momentTimeString = momentTimeObj.format('HH:mm:ss');

                    var my_input_date = $("#input_date").val();
                    var momentDateObj = moment(my_input_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var momentDateString = momentDateObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                    calEvent.start = moment(momentDateString + ' ' + momentTimeString, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");


                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    $('#modal').modal('hide');
              });       

            }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out, how to do this. In my example I'm able to change the event end-time by calculating the duration between start and end and diplay it as HH:mm. So the User can change the duration like 01:00 (hour). Also I add some additional fields like "information" and "color". After the changes in a modal (bootstrap) are made, I write it back to the calendar. Maybe there are better solutions for this, but for me it works fine.

```
  // initialize the external events

            $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

                    // Start Time: String to Date
                    var my_start_time =  new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + $(this).data('start'));
                    var start_time = moment(my_start_time).toDate();

                    // End Time: String to Date -> Date to Decimal
                    var my_dur_time = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + $(this).data('duration'));
                    var dur_time = moment(my_dur_time).format('HH:mm');
                    dur_time = moment.duration(dur_time).asHours();


                    //Add Decimal End Time to Start Time
                    var end_time = moment(start_time).add(dur_time, 'hours');


                // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                $(this).data('event', {
                    start: $(this).data('start'),
                    end: end_time,
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)

                });

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });

            });

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

//Other calendar settings here ...

eventClick: function(event, element) {



curr_event = event;
            var inp_start_time = moment(event.start).format();
            var inp_end_time = moment(event.end).format();
            var diff_time = moment(moment(inp_end_time),'mm').diff(moment(inp_start_time),'mm');
            diff_time = moment.duration(diff_time, "milliseconds");

            diff_time = moment.utc(moment.duration(diff_time).asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm");


            var my_time = moment(event.start).format('HH:mm');
            var my_date = moment(event.start).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
            var my_hidden_date = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            $("#inp_time").val(my_time); 
            $("#inp_date").val(my_date);
            $("#inp_hidden_date").val(my_hidden_date);
            $("#inp_title").val(event.title);

            $("#inp_duration").val(diff_time);

            $("#inp_information").val(event.information);
            $("#inp_color").val(event.color);       

            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }
});

        $("#button_ok").click(function (myevent) {

                var my_input_time = $("#inp_time").val();
                var momentTimeObj = moment(my_input_time, 'HH:mm:ss');
                var momentTimeString = momentTimeObj.format('HH:mm:ss');


                var my_input_date = $("#inp_hidden_date").val();
                var momentDateObj = moment(my_input_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
                var momentDateString = momentDateObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                var datetime = moment(momentDateString + ' ' + momentTimeString, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

                var my_title = $("#inp_title").val();
                var my_duration = $("#inp_duration").val();

                var new_dur_time = moment.duration(my_duration).asHours();

                //Add Decimal End Time to Start Time
                var new_end_time = moment(datetime).add(new_dur_time, 'hours');

                var new_information = $("#inp_information").val();
                var new_color = $("#inp_color").val();                  

                    $.extend(curr_event, {
                        title: my_title,
                        start: datetime,
                        end: new_end_time,
                        information: new_information,
                        color: new_color
                    });

                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent', curr_event);

        }); 

});
```

Hope this helps.

Greetings.

Comment: When you update your start or end time and then click it to update it again, what is the value of the start time? when it first renders the event off of page load it's this: "2017-10-30 12:30", however, after I do an update it changes to an array that looks like this: [2017, 9, 30, 0, 30, 0, 0]. Does this happen to you too? EDIT:

Comment: EDIT: I was able to solve this issue using refetchEvents in my ajax success call.