# How to pass startDate and event inside updateEvent of fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to pass `event name` and `startDate` inside `updateEvent()` to update current event.
Is it correct?

```
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',Diwali,2017-10-23);
```

I referred from here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140115/how-to-update-start-time-in-fullcalendar-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution: we can use `renderEvent` to render events dynamically.

```
var event={title: 'Diwali',start: new Date()}  
 $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',event,true);
```